# Fiori $expand with CRM data

Tags: sapui5, sap-fiori

I'm having some sort of rudimentary problem with navigation in my sapui5 fiori app. I'm just trying to navigate from Opportunities to Complex Notes, but it's not working at all. Here is a stripped down version of my simple view. There is no logic in any controller. As simple as I could imagine it. Because it's so simple I'm thinking I'm reading the odata wrong. So [here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1umq3jQZIB9s8luf5Vi8PMe6RubSVnbO1) is a link to that odata. I really appreciate it, I'm spinning my wheels on this one and I'm sure it's something ridiculous. Always is.

```
<mvc:View xmlns:html="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:mvc="sap.ui.core.mvc" xmlns="sap.m"
controllerName="BlankDocumentToBeDeletedLater.controller.View1" displayBlock="true">
<App>
<pages>
<Page title="{i18n>title}">
<content>
<List noDataText="Drop list items here" id="__list0" items="{ path : '/Opportunities', parameters:{'$expand' : 'ComplexNotes'}}">
    <items>
    <CustomListItem>
    <content>
    <Title text="ID : {Guid}"></Title>
        <List items="{ComplexNotes}">
        <items>
        <ObjectListItem title="whatevs" intro="{HeaderGuid}">
        </ObjectListItem>
    </items>
    </List>
    </content>
    </CustomListItem>
    </items>
</List>
</content>
</Page>
</pages>
</App>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

“$” for expand is only needed on OData V4;
“/Opportunities” into the path for “listitems”;
text=”ID: {Guid}” won’t work, it needs a formatter to join the fixed text to the Guid property;
I've never seen a list in a list – the developer should try with the parent list first.
Check in the chrome network the request and response that is created by the UI5 binding.

Comment: Yep, I should have updated my note. I'm not on OData V4 so all my struggling was in vain. As to the overall layout, It was just a demo so yea, not very well organized. I'm three weeks into this sapui5 so still making some pretty newb errors.